# read from file and convert to double in C++

Tags: c++, string, double

i have a problem with reading from a file, and converting content to double. I have read the solutions from stackoverflow but nothing works.

i have this input file:

```
1291.23
291.493
558.089
309.266
513.656
491.44
429.234
851.345
589.192
535.873
802.469
713.604
1002.42
997.973
513.656
313.709
407.018
624.738
460.337
526.986
473.667
1202.36
```

and the program:

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <string> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sstream> 

using namespace std; 
void main() { 
    char* filename = "mr1.txt"; 
    ifstream fin; 
    fin.open(filename); 
    float d;// = 0.0; 
    int v = 0; 
    while (v < 21){ 
        fin>>d; 
        if(v >= 2 || v < 15){ 
            cout<<d<<endl;
        } 
        v++; 
    } 
}
```

the output is: 1291 for 12 times

How can i convert from these file to double without problem? Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that under some locales, the decimal separator is `,`, so if you enter something with a `.` separator, the decimals will be ignored under that locales.

Comment: with `,` the output is same :(

Comment: change the `||` to `&&`, I suspect that is what you are after...

Comment: Could it be a problem with the of end of line character(s) in the original file ? They are different on each plateform. Also, if(v >= 2 || v < 15) is always true, you probably want to have if(v >= 2 && v < 15).

Comment: Try to use `std::string d` instead of `double d`, to see if there are conversion errors that you don't see. Also, try to print something before and after `d`, like `cout << "-- " << d << " --" << endl`, to see the entries of the file are separated.

Comment: You say `double` but your code says `float`.

Comment: Use `cmath` and `cstdio` (instead of `math.h` and `stdio.h`) in C++, please.

Comment: works fine for me (after changing main's definition to `int main`) when compiled with gcc 4.4.5. I suspect it is a locale problem.

Comment: Your entrypoint function (if without arguments) _must_ be `int main()`. Not `void` (although you may omit `return 0` in this function _only_ if you like). Also, that trailing `;` is wrong.

Comment: Don't you get a warning about `char* myString = "string literal"` not being a `const` pointer? I could go on...

Comment: @moala: Unless you explicitly set your application to be local aware it uses the "C" locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick sanity check, try just copying the entire file to standard output, something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {    
    std::ifstream in("mr1.txt");
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<double>(in),
              std::istream_iterator<double>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong with your code, but none which would
explain the symptom you describe (which is impossible with the code
you've posted: you loop 40 times, and output every time in the loop).
Anyway:

- You've got the condition in the `if` wrong, so it's always true:
      `v` is always either greater than 2 or less than 15,

  You've got the condition in the `while` wrong; you're attempting
      to read 40 values, regardless of what's in the file

What your loop probably should look like is:

```
while ( fin >> d ) {
    if ( v >= 2 && v < 15 ) {
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    }
    ++ v;
}
```

This will cause the elements [2, 15) to be displayed, provided they're
present.

If you're always displaying the same value, it's probably that the input
after that value failed, given that you don't test whether your input
succeeded or not.  One possible explination is the one moala mentionned
in a note: when you open a file, it is imbued with the current global
locale.  Try:

```
fin.imbue(std::locale("C"));
```

immediately after opening the file; in most locales, the decimal
separator is a comma, not a point.  (Also: check that the open
succeeded.)

Comment: that's the point. the reading from file failed. a restart for my pc and all worked fine :) funny stuff, not? PS: these code was an example. not condition was the problem

Answer (score 1):

You see the last 15 lines of the output of your program, because the `v` variable continues growing over the number of lines in the data file.

Change `while (v < 40)` to `while(v < 21)` and you will see what you expect to see.

Comment: the out put must be for first line from file (double)1291.23 and so on with every line from file

Comment: @Umelinho post your complete program, this snippet seems to be (almost) correct.

Comment: The code is missing *at least* included headers, `using` directives, the declaration of the `main()` function.

Answer (score 1):

- Check your line endings
- don't forget to call getline() ( http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/777/ )

Answer (score 1):

James Kanze has the best advice thus far as far as how to iterate through the file. But i'm pretty sure it should be:

```
std::cout << d << std::endl;
```

Otherwise you'll be printing out line numbers.

Also, I'd like to point out you have a lot of unnecessary includes. Not that it matters, but all you really need at this point is iostream and fstream. Everything else is excess.

One last thing. If you need the input to be doubles, why are you putting them into a float variable?